# If text in two cells exist, this creates a unique number

Tags: excel, if-statement, numbers, unique, cells

I am working with an excel file where I need a unique number created if the text in two cells are present: example

```
Text 1     Text 2       Value
star       comet        100
star       asteroid     101
asteroid   nova         102
nova       star         103
asteroid   nova         102
star       comet        100
nova       star         103
```

I assume its something to do with the IF function but I'm now completely snowblind.  Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sort by column1 then by column 2

Use the Excel `distinct` function

Then add sequential ID to each row.

If you need to, use `VLOOKUP` to add the IDs to the original sheet

Comment: Sorry (misremembered) - in Excel 2013 it's called 'Remove Duplicates' and is on the 'Data' tab of the ribbon

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting, array formulae or VBA and assuming `Text 1` is in A1, select ColumnsA:B, DATA > Sort & Filter - Advanced, Copy to: F1 (say), check Unique record only. In H2:

```
=F2&"|"&G2
```

in I2 enter `100` and copy H2:I2 down to suit.

In C2:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2&"|"&B2,H:I,2,0)
```

and copy down to suit.

A PivotTable is an alternative for constructing a list of unique pairs.